# isNaN isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, html

This is the attribute I put on a text box to restrict input to numbers.

```
 onKeyPress="if(isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode))) event.preventDefault();"
```

Working perfect with google chrome. isNaN function return **true** for non-numeric keyPress and return **false** for every numeric keyPress. But in firefox isNaN function return true for both numeric and non-numeric key press's.

I read isNaN function cross-browser supported but it isn't works fine in firefox. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The event should be `onkeypress` not `onKeyPress`;

Comment: @ThankYouSRT—it appears to be an inline listener, so the attribute name is not case sensitive and any capitalisation is OK.

Answer (score 4):

Confusing special-case behavior with `isNaN()`

Since the very earliest versions of the isNaN function specification, its behavior for non-numeric arguments has been confusing. When the argument to the isNaN function is not of type Number, the value is first coerced to a Number. The resulting value is then tested to determine whether it is NaN. Thus for non-numbers that when coerced to numeric type result in a valid non-NaN numeric value (notably the empty string and boolean primitives, which when coerced give numeric values zero or one), the "false" returned value may be unexpected; the empty string, for example, is surely "not a number." The confusion stems from the fact that the term, "not a number", has a specific meaning for numbers represented as IEEE-794 floating-point values. The function should be interpreted as answering the question, "is this value, when coerced to a numeric value, an IEEE-794 'Not A Number' value?"

The next version of ECMAScript (ES6) contains the function Number.isNaN function. Number.isNaN(x) will be a reliable way to test whether x is NaN or not. Even with Number.isNaN, however, the meaning of NaN remains the precise numeric meaning, and not simply, "not a number". Alternatively, in absense of Number.isNaN, the expression (x != x) is a more reliable way to test whether variable x is NaN or not, as the result is not subject to the false positives that make isNaN unreliable.

**Examples:**

```
    isNaN(NaN);       // true
    isNaN(undefined); // true
    isNaN({});        // true

    isNaN(true);      // false
    isNaN(null);      // false
    isNaN(37);        // false

    // strings
    isNaN("37");      // false: "37" is converted to the number 37 which is not NaN
    isNaN("37.37");   // false: "37.37" is converted to the number 37.37 which is not NaN
    isNaN("");        // false: the empty string is converted to 0 which is not NaN
    isNaN(" ");       // false: a string with spaces is converted to 0 which is not NaN

    // This is a false positive and the reason why isNaN is not entirely reliable
    isNaN("blabla")   // true: "blabla" is converted to a number. Parsing this as a number fails and returns NaN
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: sorry but this explanation is completely unrelated to the case the op described and absolutely unrelated to isNaN  behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to check that input is a number, a better way to test is to look at the actual value of the input:

```
onblur="if (/\D/.test(this.value)) alert('there\'s a non-digit in the value');"
```

The above is "better" as values can be entered without pressing any keys, thereby not causing a keypress event, also the keyCode may resolve to an unexpected value. All you really care about is the value of the control, not how it got there.

Also, please don't restrict what the user can type into the control, just test the value at the time you want to use it (e.g. on form submission or when the control loses focus). Often users will strike an incorrect key and happily fix the error themselves. Throwing up an error or deleting the character automatically before the user has a chance to do it themselve makes the control harder to use, not easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

`onKeyPress="if(isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode))) event.preventDefault();"`

will not work on any version of Mozilla browsers, because moz doesn't expose events. No matter how counterintuitive, moz browsers will require a function with a declared argument name, say function(e){...; at which they arbitrary assign the event object on functions triggered by events.

Since you are accessing the event object globally, and it's not there[!], - this declaration

`String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)`

will either trigger an error; or Firefox made compromise that when a property of undefined 'event' keyword has been called, to return `undefined` value which the test

`isNaN(undefined);`

always evaluate as *true*.

And that's why you are getting *true* for all kinds of characters being typed there - be it a letter, or a numeral - regardless.